# How to insert a file name after a variable in terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am building a tf script that automates the deployment of multiple applications. Some of the cloud resources deployed are VMs and they require some scripts to run after deployment. To automate this task, I've declared several variables that map these scripts.

Today, it works like the example below:

I have dozens of script variables declared on the *variables.tf* file

```
variable "path_script_backend" {
  type        = string
  description = "The path to the backend script"
  default = "/application/scripts/backend.sh"
}
```

Then, I use the variable to run the necessary scripts on the instances

*application.tf*

```
# Connect to the instance via Terraform and remotely executes the install script using SSH

    provisioner "file" {
        source      = var.path_script_backend
        destination = "/tmp/backend.sh"
      }
    
      provisioner "remote-exec" {
        inline = [
          "sudo chmod +x /tmp/backend.sh",
          "sudo /tmp/backend.sh"
        ]
      }
```

It all works fine but the feedback I received from the ops team is that this takes a lot of time for them to copy and paste these file paths across multiple application scripts and they want me to simply use one variable to map the folder where the scripts are located.

With that, I tried the following approach:

*variables.tf*

```
variable "folder_scripts" {
  type        = string
  description = "The path to the scripts folder"
  default = "/application/scripts"
}
```

Then, I use the folder variable + file name to run the necessary scripts on the instances

*application.tf*

```
# Connect to the instance via Terraform and remotely executes the install script using SSH

    provisioner "file" {
        source      = var.folder_scripts"/backend.sh"
        destination = "/tmp/backend.sh"
      }
```

But the above doesn't work as terraform doesn't like the format. I tried different combinations and regex to match the file but to no avail.

Any ideas of what I can do to fix it?

Tks in advance

Comment: try using `source = "${var.folder_scripts}/backend.sh"`

Comment: Tks! That did the trick :)

Comment: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/strings.html#interpolation